# How do I debug error ECONNRESET in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, express

I'm running an Express.js application using Socket.io for a chat webapp
and I get the following error randomly around 5 times during 24h.
The node process is wrapped in forever and it restarts itself immediately.

The problem is that restarting Express kicks my users out of their rooms 
and nobody wants that.

The web server is proxied by HAProxy. There are no socket stability issues, 
just using websockets and flashsockets transports.
I cannot reproduce this on purpose.

This is the error with Node `v0.10.11`:

```
    events.js:72
            throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
                  ^
    Error: read ECONNRESET     //alternatively it s a 'write'
        at errnoException (net.js:900:11)
        at TCP.onread (net.js:555:19)
    error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
    error: Forever restarting script for 2 time
```

**EDIT (2013-07-22)**

Added both socket.io client error handler and the uncaught exception handler.
Seems that this one catches the error:

```
    process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
      console.error(err.stack);
      console.log("Node NOT Exiting...");
    });
```

So I suspect it's not a Socket.io issue but an HTTP request to another server 
that I do or a MySQL/Redis connection. The problem is that the error stack 
doesn't help me identify my code issue. Here is the log output:

```
    Error: read ECONNRESET
        at errnoException (net.js:900:11)
        at TCP.onread (net.js:555:19)
```

How do I know what causes this? How do I get more out of the error?

Ok, not very verbose but here's the stacktrace with Longjohn:

```
    Exception caught: Error ECONNRESET
    { [Error: read ECONNRESET]
      code: 'ECONNRESET',
      errno: 'ECONNRESET',
      syscall: 'read',
      __cached_trace__:
       [ { receiver: [Object],
           fun: [Function: errnoException],
           pos: 22930 },
         { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function: onread], pos: 14545 },
         {},
         { receiver: [Object],
           fun: [Function: fireErrorCallbacks],
           pos: 11672 },
         { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function], pos: 12329 },
         { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function: onread], pos: 14536 } ],
      __previous__:
       { [Error]
         id: 1061835,
         location: 'fireErrorCallbacks (net.js:439)',
         __location__: 'process.nextTick',
         __previous__: null,
         __trace_count__: 1,
         __cached_trace__: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } }
```

Here I serve the flash socket policy file:

```
    net = require("net")
    net.createServer( (socket) =>
      socket.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n")
      socket.write("<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM \"http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd\">\n")
      socket.write("<cross-domain-policy>\n")
      socket.write("<allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"*\"/>\n")
      socket.write("</cross-domain-policy>\n")
      socket.end()
    ).listen(843)
```

Can this be the cause?

Comment: @GottZ maybe this can help (spoke to someone working within node js) https://gist.github.com/samsonradu/1b0c6feb438f5a53e30e. I ll deploy the socket.error handler today and let you know.

Comment: @Gottz the socket.error handles doesn t help, but process.on('uncaughtException') catches the error. Here is the console.log of the error: { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }

Comment: ECONNRESET could be from network problem. As you know it is impossible to catch all the exceptions when testing. Some will show up on your production server. You will have to make your server robust. You can handle the session deletion by using Redis as storage. It makes your sessions persist even after your node server goes down.

Comment: Why is that related with session deletion? They are handled by Redis anyway.

Comment: This seams to me as you are getting a socket timeout from one of your connected clients. Try to add an 'error' listener to all your connections, not the process itself.

Comment: net.js does a lot of debuglog-ing when it's going to emit an error, you might get some mileage out of setting env.NODE_DEBUG="net" and then matching the output up against source locations.

Comment: @Moss define connected clients. The node server only listens to websocket connections and they have an error handler added.

Comment: You have at-least one TCP socket listening that does not have the handler set. So now it's time to check where that one is :D

Comment: just as note: in my case this happens with a childprocesses stdio and not a tcp socket or anything else. just raw stdio. will try that uncaughtException event now. thanks.

Comment: Can you show the relevant code from your server where the error occurs. Or at least some minimal code to reproduce the error. It is difficult without looking at the code.

Comment: @user568109 here are some relevant parts (if you re fine with Coffeescript) https://gist.github.com/samsonradu/5585b0f4a101fee3cab4

Comment: https://github.com/joyent/node/releases/tag/v0.10.12 seeing a fix to socket writes. will upgrade

Comment: Simply adding `process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) { ... })` sorted this for me. It doesn't get to the root of the problem but the error is rare enough for me that this quick and dirty solution is fine for my use case.

Comment: Related: if anyone sees this happening on some cloud/PaaS offerings, it could be because the instances are throttling down (during quiet times).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A simple tcp server I had for serving the flash policy file was causing this. I can now catch the error using a handler:

```
# serving the flash policy file
net = require("net")

net.createServer((socket) =>
  //just added
  socket.on("error", (err) =>
    console.log("Caught flash policy server socket error: ")
    console.log(err.stack)
  )

  socket.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n")
  socket.write("<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM \"http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd\">\n")
  socket.write("<cross-domain-policy>\n")
  socket.write("<allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"*\"/>\n")
  socket.write("</cross-domain-policy>\n")
  socket.end()
).listen(843)
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the code? Should I have checked if the socket is writable before writing?

Comment: Doh, didn't see that you already found the solution before I posted pretty much the same thing :) As to your question though, even if you check that the socket is writable, it may not be when you write to it microseconds later and would still throw an error, so this is "the way" to be sure.

Comment: ok, and is there a safe way out if this? like socket.close() inside the error handler? because i think my CPU load is increasing after these errors (not sure)

Comment: I've always called `socket.destroy()` in the error handler to make sure. Sadly I can't find documentation whether it is required, but it does not emit an error to do so.

Comment: socket.destroy()  saved my day, whatever it works !! Thank you!

Answer (score 386):

You might have guessed it already: it's a connection error.

*"ECONNRESET"* means the other side of the TCP conversation abruptly closed its end of the connection. This is most probably due to one or more application protocol errors. You could look at the API server logs to see if it complains about something.

But since you are also looking for a way to check the error and potentially debug the problem, you should take a look at *"[How to debug a socket hang up error in NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11542134/2432317)"* which was posted at stackoverflow in relation to an alike question.

> **Quick and dirty solution for development**:

> Use  [longjohn](https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn), you get long stack traces that will contain the async operations.

> 

**Clean and correct solution**:
Technically, in node, whenever [you emit an `'error'` event and no one listens to it, it will throw](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_class_events_eventemitter). To make it not throw, put a listener on it and handle  it yourself. That way you can log the error with more information.

> To have one listener for a group of calls you can use [domains](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_domain)  and also catch other errors on runtime. Make sure each async operation related to http(Server/Client) is in different [domain](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_domain) context comparing to the other parts of the code, the domain will automatically listen to the `error` events and will propagate it to its own handler. So you only listen to that handler and get the error data. [You also get more information for free.](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_additions_to_error_objects)

**EDIT (2013-07-22)**

As I wrote above:

> *"ECONNRESET"* means the other side of the TCP conversation abruptly closed its end of the connection. This is most probably due to one or more application protocol errors. You could look at the API server logs to see if it complains about something.

What could also be the case: at random times, the other side is overloaded and simply kills the connection as a result. If that's the case, depends on what you're connecting to exactly…

But one thing's for sure: you indeed have a read error on your TCP connection which causes the exception. You can see that by looking at the error code you posted in your edit, which confirms it.

Comment: It doesn't have to mean 'abruptly closed'. It usually results from writing to a connection which the peer had already closed normally. That will cause it to issue an RST.

Comment: @EJP There was a good reason why I wrote “abruptly”. The error (not warning) states the connection was reset by peer. **An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote peer.** A forced close is abrupt since unexpected! (This normally results if peer application on remote machine is suddenly stopped, machine is rebooted, or peer application used a "hard close" on the remote socket. This error may also result if a connection was broken due to "keep-alive" activity detecting a failure while one or more operations are in progress… these operations and subsequent operations will fail.)

Comment: I get this error thrown when I batch send around 100 API calls near concurrently from the browser (Chrome) for testing. I imagine that Chrome must then become overloaded and kill some of the connections...

@Samson - what is wrong with processing each request in its own domain and catching domain errors without restarting the server?

Comment: @supershnee You should almost always restart your server after an uncaught exception since your data, application, and node.js itself is in an unknown state.  Continuing after an exception puts your data a risk.  If you want to find out more, check out [Node's docs on process](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception) or [Node's docs on domains](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html).

Comment: Does this error comes in production ??

Answer (score 39):

I had a similar problem where apps started erroring out after an upgrade of Node.  I believe this can be traced back to Node release v0.9.10 this item:

- net: don't suppress ECONNRESET (Ben Noordhuis)

Previous versions wouldn't error out on interruptions from the client.  A break in the connection from the client throws the error ECONNRESET in Node.  I believe this is intended functionality for Node, so the fix (at least for me) was to handle the error, which I believe you did in unCaught exceptions.  Although I handle it in the net.socket handler.

You can demonstrate this:

Make a simple socket server and get Node v0.9.9 and v0.9.10.

```
require('net')
    .createServer( function(socket) 
    {
           // no nothing
    })
    .listen(21, function()
     {
           console.log('Socket ON')
    })
```

Start it up using v0.9.9 and then attempt to FTP to this server. I'm using FTP and port 21 only because I'm on Windows and have an FTP client, but no telnet client handy.

Then from the client side, just break the connection. (I'm just doing Ctrl-C)

You should see NO ERROR when using Node v0.9.9, and ERROR when using Node v.0.9.10 and up.

In production, I use v.0.10. something and it still gives the error. Again, I think this is intended and the solution is to handle the error in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I nailed it myself! It s important not to let errors propagate to uncaughtException because it renders the whole app unstable. E.g. after catching around 10 ECONNRESET errors the server sometimes became unresponsive (just froze and didn t handle any connections)

Comment: Also knew about the node version change that didn t suppress the error any more, but seeing so many issues showing up and being solved each version I d rather go for the latest one. I m using V0.10.13 now btw

Answer (score 25):

Had the same problem today.
After some research i found a very useful [`--abort-on-uncaught-exception` node.js option](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_abort_on_uncaught_exception). Not only it provides much more verbose and useful error stack trace, but also saves core file on application crash allowing further debug.

Comment: weird that a new answer to this old question should pop up as I'm looking -- but this is great, thanks

Answer (score 19):

I also get ECONNRESET error during my development, the way I solve it is by **not** using nodemon to start my server, just use `"node server.js"` to start my server fixed my problem.

It's weird, but it worked for me, now I never see the ECONNRESET error again.

Comment: Any idea how you came up with this solution? You just randomly tried it. This helped me too.

Answer (score 16):

I was facing the same issue but I mitigated it by placing:

```
server.timeout = 0;
```

before `server.listen`. `server` is an HTTP server here. The default timeout is 2 minutes as per the [API documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html).

Comment: This isn't a solution but rather a quickfix which will breaks things without throwing an error.

Comment: I believe for me the problem was it timing out after a period of 5 minutes or so, would it stilll be a problem?

Comment: Having no timeout could leave you vulnerable to DOS via http vectors

Answer (score 12):

Yes, your serving of the policy file can definitely cause the crash.

To repeat, just add a delay to your code:

```
net.createServer( function(socket) 
{
    for (i=0; i<1000000000; i++) ;
    socket.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n");
…
```

… and use `telnet` to connect to the port. If you disconnect telnet before the delay has expired, you'll get a crash (uncaught exception) when socket.write throws an error.

To avoid the crash here, just add an error handler before reading/writing the socket:

```
net.createServer(function(socket)
{
    for(i=0; i<1000000000; i++);
    socket.on('error', function(error) { console.error("error", error); });
    socket.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n");
}
```

When you try the above disconnect, you'll just get a log message instead of a crash.

And when you're done, remember to remove the delay.

Answer (score 11):

Another possible case (but rare) could be if you have server to server communications and have set `server.maxConnections` to a very low value.

In node's core lib [net.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/c9b59e8387b08dab20936f32d2b290804718f688/lib/net.js#L1432-L1435) it will call `clientHandle.close()` which will also cause error ECONNRESET:

```
if (self.maxConnections && self._connections >= self.maxConnections) {
  clientHandle.close(); // causes ECONNRESET on the other end
  return;
}
```

Comment: Great call, but `maxConnections` default value is `Infinity`. This would be only the case (as you said) if you have explicitly overridden that value.

Answer (score 9):

*ECONNRESET* occurs when the server side closes the TCP connection and your request to the server is not fulfilled. The server responds with the message that the connection, you are referring to a invalid connection.

*Why the server sends a request with invalid connection?*

Suppose you have enabled a keep-alive connection between client and server. The keep-alive timeout is configured to 15 seconds. This means that if keep-alive is idle for 15 seconds, it will send connection close request. So after 15 seconds, server tells the client to close the connection. **BUT**, when server is sending this request, client is sending a new request which is already on flight to the server end. Since this connection is invalid now, server will reject with ECONNRESET error. So the problem occurs due to fewer requests to the server end. So please disable keep-alive and it will work fine.

Comment: Can this happen the other way around? I mean, the client closed the connection but the server is trying to push data using the same connection? In this scenario do we get the same error on the server side log?

Comment: how to disable keep-alive?

Answer (score 8):

I had this Error too and was able to solve it after days of debugging and analysis:

## my solution

For me VirtualBox (for Docker) was the Problem. I had Port Forwarding configured on my VM and the error only occured on the forwarded port.

## general conclusions

The following observations may save you days of work I had to invest:

- For me the problem only occurred on connections from localhost to localhost on one port. -> check changing any of these constants solves the problem.
- For me the problem only occurred on my machine -> let someone else try it.
- For me the problem only occurred after a while and couldn't be reproduced reliably
- My Problem couldn't be inspected with any of nodes or expresses (debug-)tools. -> don't waste time on this

**-> figure out if something is messing around with your network (-settings), like VMs, Firewalls etc., this is probably the cause of the problem.**

Answer (score 7):

I solved the problem by simply **connecting to a different network**. That is one of the possible problems.

As discussed above, *ECONNRESET* means that the TCP conversation abruptly closed its end of the connection.

Your internet connection might be blocking you from connecting to some servers. In my case, I was trying to connect to mLab ( cloud database service that hosts MongoDB databases). And my ISP is blocking it.

Comment: This one worked for me, my code which was working fine few hours back suddenly stopped working , turns out, the network change caused the problem

Comment: For me two, thanks :) I was connected to a **very poor wifi** (but didn't know), I switch to another wifi extender to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

I had resolved this problem by:

- Turning off my wifi/ethernet connection and turn on.
- I typed: `npm update` in terminal to update npm.
- I tried to log out from the session and log in again

After that I tried the same npm command and the good thing was it worked out. I wasn't sure it is that simple.

I am using CENTOS 7

Answer (score 5):

I just figured this out, at least in my use case.

I was getting `ECONNRESET`. It turned out that the way my client was set up, it was hitting the server with an API call a ton of times really quickly -- and it only needed to hit the endpoint once.

When I fixed that, the error was gone.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and it appears that the Node.js version was the problem.

I installed the previous version of Node.js (10.14.2) and everything was ok using nvm (allow you to install several version of Node.js and quickly switch from a version to another).

It is not a "clean" solution, but it can serve you temporarly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these options to socket.io:

```
const options = { transports: ['websocket'], pingTimeout: 3000, pingInterval: 5000 };
```

I hope this will help you !

Answer (score 0):

Node JS socket  is non-blocking io. Consider using a non-blocking io connection from other sources. For instance, if you use a blocking Java socket with node it will only work for a few seconds after which the error will be served. Mitigate this by implementing a non-blocking connection I.e. socketchannel with the selector.

Answer (score 0):

First I run my app I got **ECONNRESET** after that I got error like **ECONNREFUSED** . I had faced both of this problem while running my **node** **app**.For both of the Problem, I found that this was occuring because of **not** **starting the wampserver**.I am using *mysql* database in my app for getting the data with the help of wampserver. I resolve this by *starting the wampserver and then after running my node app*. It works fine.You can use node or nodemon for running the node application It's not the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Few options I tried and worked as a temporary solutions

1. If using node, try to switch between different node versions using `node use #version#`. Worked for me
2. Try switching internet connection

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `node` version was the problem. The application gave error **ECONNRESET** with `v16.14.2` but it worked fine with `v18.16.0`. I use [n](https://github.com/tj/n) to manage `node` versions.