# Node - Request.js ECONNRESET Error Only On Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I have a script on a server that looks like this.

```
request = require('request');
require('longjohn');
request.post(
    { 
        url : 'https://example.com/api/thing/',
        form : {
            api_key : "blahblah",
            thing_id : 0
        },
        json : true
    },
    function(error, response, body){
        console.log(error, response);
    }
);
```

When i run it locally, It works perfectly, but when I run it on the server i get this.

```
{ [Error: read ECONNRESET]
code: 'ECONNRESET',
errno: 'ECONNRESET',
syscall: 'read',
__cached_trace__: 
[ { receiver: [Object],
   fun: [Function: errnoException],
   pos: 22969 },
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function: onread], pos: 14584 },
 {},
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function], pos: 19529 },
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function], pos: 49346 },
 { receiver: [Object],
   fun: [Function: _tickCallback],
   pos: 14030 },
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function], pos: 14031 },
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Object], pos: 4502 },
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function], pos: 28039 },
 {},
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function], pos: 48679 },
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function], pos: 36057 },
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Object], pos: 40546 },
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function], pos: 3570 },
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function], pos: 17260 },
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function], pos: 36440 },
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function], pos: 11960 },
 {},
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function], pos: 11634 },
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Object], pos: 2292 },
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Object], pos: 1738 },
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function], pos: 3238 },
 { receiver: {}, fun: [Function], pos: 121 },
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function], pos: 12854 },
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function], pos: 13365 },
 { receiver: [Object], fun: [Function], pos: 10114 } ],
 __previous__: 
 { [Error]
 id: 73,
 location: 'Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:679)',
 __location__: 'EventEmitter.on',
 __previous__: 
  { [Error]
    id: 60,
    location: 'ClientRequest.onSocket (http.js:1700)',
    __location__: 'process.nextTick',
    __previous__: [Object],
    __trace_count__: 2,
    __cached_trace__: [Object] },
 __trace_count__: 3,
 __cached_trace__: 
  [ [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    {},
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    {},
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object] ] } }
```

I am not familiar with the specifics of tcp sockets. If anyone has any thoughts or if you need more information, let me know.

Comment: does any of this look actionable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset

Answer (score 0):

This ended up getting solved by our rackspace managed support team - it was a hardware configuration issue.

> It looks like your problem is some where between the firewall and the
>   load balancer.
>
> It appears this issue is being caused by the DNS doctoring from the
>   firewall.
>
> If I set in the /etc/hosts file on xxx-node-prod-1 that the ip address
>   for production.xxx.com is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, everything works perfectly.
>
> The problem appears when the curl command is hitting the private
>   natted ip of the load balancer.

we use a hardware FW and LB for this setup and something on their side was screwy.