# Nodejs socket connection error

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have written this code that sends packet to a socket and reads from it. But when i run it , i get the data from socket but the code throws an error by saying read ECONNRESET. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
var client = net.connect({port:remotePort, host:remoteIpAddress},function(){    
    client.write(packet);
});
client.on('data',function(chunkData){       
    console.log(chunkData);
    client.end();
}); 

client.on('end',function(){
    console.log("Reading end");
});

client.on('error', function(err){
    console.log("Error: "+err.message);
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should be ok. `ECONNRESET` means the other side of the socket unexpectedly aborted the connection. It's not your client code causing this error.

See also [previous question on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset)