# Web App database ECONNRESET

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, bookshelf.js

I have a expressjs application hosted on Azure web app with Always On enabled.

I am using bookshelfjs to connect to the MySQL database which is hosted in another virtual server on Azure.

After sometime, when I call the web application I get below error, which told me it failed to connect to the database server:

```
select * from `member` where `name` = 'alvin' limit 1 -read ECONNRESET"
```

Is it related to the expressjs timeout problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the similar issue on SO [MySQL giving "read ECONNRESET" error after idle time on node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900931/mysql-giving-read-econnreset-error-after-idle-time-on-node-js-server), it seems to be a MySQL connection issue.

As the answer said:

> MySQL does indeed prune idle connections.

Please try to add the `pool` setting in the MySQL connection configuration in `Knex`. E.G,

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'your_database_user',
    password : 'your_database_password',
    database : 'myapp_test'
  },
  pool: {
    min: 0,
    max: 7
  }
});
```

Please refer to http://knexjs.org/#Installation-pooling for more info.