# Handling Azure SQL errors in Node

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure, exception

I'm using Azure MySQL database in my Node application which works fine except that after few minutes of usage, Azure closes the connection and Node throws error:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
```

What I need is to prevent my Node app from crashing and tell it to reconnect after such exception. I have tried:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "mydatabase.mysql.database.azure.com",
  user: "nodeapp@mydatabase",
  password: "12345",
  database: "mydatabase",
  port: 3306
});

    process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
      con.destroy();
      con.connect();
      console.log(err);
    });
```

This prevents app from crashing, but my app cannot write to database after this so reconnection fails. How should I reconnect after such error? Any advise is highly appreciated.

Comment: Any advise guys? I'm not looking for the source of error, rather some way to reconnect when error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reproduced your error: Throw the below error after connecting about 3 minutes.

[image]

The reason seems to be some settings on your database like this: `wait_timeout=180`.

## My solutions:

**1. raise the value of wait_timeout:**
[image]

**2. If this happens when establishing a single reused connection, it can be avoided by establishing a connection pool instead.** See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37326025/13586071).

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort. Yeah the exception handling code prevents app from crashing but unfortunately does not reconnect properly. But raising the value of timeout parameter should work, thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it helps, I would delete the useless part in my answer.