# Node.js error: ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead

Tags: node.js

[Node.js ECONNRESET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSC9m.png)

Hey guys, I want to ask if anyone knows what cause the problem.

System: Raspberry Pi OS
Database: mariaDB

Rest-API is based on node.js with express and other dependicies.

Thanks

Comment: How long after the successful connection?

Comment: I will try the solution with server.timeout(0);
How long? I do not know the exact time yet. I guess around midnight.

Comment: Since this is also probably related to MySQL own timeout setting, you may try using `createPool` as well. Here's a reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/37326025/10910692

Comment: I will try it. Can take some time. To be more exactly I use mariadb

Comment: UPDATE: It does not only happen at midnight. I restarted the Raspberry PI and I will look

Comment: [Please do not post images of code, error messages or data when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)