# what causing this problem, after connecting to the mysql database this error pops up on the console on its own

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
node:events:492 Uncaught Error: read ECONNRESET
    at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (node:internal/errors:496:5)
    at __node_internal_errnoException (node:internal/errors:623:12)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
```

what causing this problem as after connecting to the mysql database this error pops up on the console on its own.

Comment: what have you researched about the `ECONNRESET` error - the description of such error should be all you need to know to fix your issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL giving "read ECONNRESET" error after idle time on node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900931/mysql-giving-read-econnreset-error-after-idle-time-on-node-js-server)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should `catch` the error, so you app can handle it properly and doesn't crash when mysql connection is closed for any odd reason. Try either with `connection.on('error', ...)` or with [try-catch blocks](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_propagation_and_interception).

For keeping an open connection, you should either reconnect on close. Or simply use mysql's [pooling connection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections), which handles automatic reconnection very well, with a single code change.

PS: Pooling multiple connections is a generally good idea for async apps, like servers, but it's safe to maintain a single connection via pooling `(connectionLimit : 1)` just for automatic reconnection itself.

PPS: Mysql's inactivity timeout can be configured in server's `my.cnf`