# Exception in Node server that uses http module

Tags: node.js, http

### Please note that the above "possible answer" questions does not contain an answer to my question.  I am using require("http"). In that question the person is taking a socket input variable that they can put a handler on. I do not have the same variable.

I have a very simple server that I have written in Node.

```
var http = require("http");
var sys = require("sys");
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  target: "someServer"
});
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    try {
      proxy.web(request,response);
    } catch (err) {
        sys.puts("I caught an error!");
    }
}).listen(5000);
```

When I leave my app running, it crashes.  My command line says:

```
events.js:72

        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at errnoException (net.js:900:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:555:19)
```

It seems to crash not when server is serving files, but when it is waiting for a long time between requests.

While my code is a little more complex, I do have error catching on every callback.

Why is it crashing?  What can I do?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset

Comment: @jgillich No, it is similar.  I am using require("http").  In that question the person is taking a socket input variable that they can put a handler on.  I do not have the same variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In node, sprinkling `try` and `catch` everywhere is not the same as catching every error.  (And in most cases, doing so is useless.)  Asynchronous operations cannot throw useful exceptions because control long ago left the block of code that invoked the operation.

Instead, many objects emit an `error` *event*.  The `error` event is a [special case](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.26/lib/events.js#L59-78) in that node will throw a "real" exception if there are no listeners for the event.  Because this exception is thrown from code you do not and cannot control (ie wrap with `try`/`catch`), it goes uncaught and the process ends.

So if you do not add an `error` listener to sockets, a socket error will bring down the entire app.

However, your unhandled error is not coming from your http requests.  The http module [adds an `error` handler to every socket automatically](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.26/lib/http.js#L1960-1962), and re-emits the error as a `clientError` event on the `Server`.  Because `EventEmitters` only *throw* when the event is named `error`, the fact that you don't handle `clientError` does not matter.

If we read http-proxy's [documentation, we see that it also throws an `error` event](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#listening-for-proxy-events), and you aren't listening for it.  Thus, your app dies whenever there's an error fetching something from an upstream server.

Add an `error` handler.

```
proxy.on('error', function (err, req, res) {
  res.writeHead(500, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  });
  res.end('Something went wrong.');
  console.error(err);
});
```

---

**Any time** you see this error ("`// Unhandled 'error' event`"), it means you need to find out what is emitting an `error` event and add a listener to handle the error.

Comment: Great answer!  Thanks!  I went crazy with my error catching.  I even made a function that wraps all my callbacks in error handling.

Comment: *Something* has to be emitting a unhandled error event.  **In development only,** you can listen to the [`uncaughtException` event from `process`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception), and maybe use [longjohn](https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn) to get a more helpful stack trace.  Remember, do not do this in production, and do not just use the event to ignore the error; the only sane thing to do when you have an uncaught exception is print a stack trace and exit.

Comment: Thanks!  Dumb question: Do I have to do anything other than require("longjohn") for longjohn to work?  I added that to my code, and I'm not really seeing a difference.

Comment: I don't think so.  Another approach is to use [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) to set a breakpoint in `uncaughtException` handler (or just write a `debugger;`) and then poke around when it breaks.