# Error: read ECONNRESET using the request module for mode.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to download and parse some big xml files. The files are from some affiliates sites that don't have a proper API right now. I use the request module for nodejs but I allways get the same error.

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
at TCP.onread (net.js:559:26)
```

If I load the same url in the browser or I user curl from the command line I get the results.

```
request('[my-url].xml', function(err, response, body){
    // I get the error here in err
});
```

Any ideea how can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Any useful answers here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset

Comment: Did you try to use node's [`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) directly without the `request` module?

Comment: thank you for your suggestions guys, @thorn I use now http.request with the "Connection":"keep-alive" option and is working great, thank you!

Comment: @biancamihai Did it happen in the middle of download or sometime after it? I'm fighting a similar issue with jsdom that uses `request` internally. But those `ECONNRESET` exceptions happen a few minutes after the request has been completed.

Comment: @thorn in my case it happened in the middle of the download, but this is a big file ... adding the same header also works with request in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Two extremely useful troubleshooting tools:

- [longjohn](https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn)
- [Fiddler2](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler)

See also:

- [Node js ECONNRESET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset)
- [Telerik forums: Node.js traffic](http://www.telerik.com/forums/node-js-traffic)

ADDENDUM:

- I would definitely encourage you to explore [longjohn](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/npmawesome-full-stack-traces-with-longjohn/), [Fiddler2](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/npmawesome-full-stack-traces-with-longjohn/) and/or other tools for troubleshooting the HTTP-level requests/responses to and from your application.
- I noticed joews and I both cited the same Stack Overflow link.  Useful takeways:

  a. `--abort-on-uncaught-exception` node.js option: Not only it provides much more verbose and useful error stack trace, but also saves core file on application crash allowing further debug.

  b. I was facing the same issue but I mitigated it by placing `server.timeout = 0;` before `server.listen`.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, it was a ""Connection":"keep-alive"" - problem, using this parameter is working