# What is causing Node to randomly fail with

Tags: node.js

I have a node application that I run behind a proxy and make requests using the request lib. Everything works fine under most circumstances but every now and then (once every few minutes) I see the following error

```
{ [Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
There was an error {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
```

Finally after a minute or so it starts working again. Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node js ECONNRESET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset)

Comment: Thanks I will look at that and ensure it is the same issue, than I will delete if appropriate

Comment: No problem! Hope it helps <3