# How many concurrent http request should I send?

Tags: node.js, http, asynchronous, network-programming

I need to send around 50 or 60 get requests at the same time to a distant server.

I don't know a lot about networking.

I just realized that for example:

sending 5 requests 10 times was totally different than sending 50 requests at the same time...

How can I know what's the most "efficient" number of concurrent HTTP requests to be send at the same time?

Comment: It's hard to say what's "efficient". Efficiency would mean there's a benefit in terms of outcome vs. effort. Moreover, in your situation, can you explain whether the requests are heavy (e.g. impacting a database), or lightweight (e.g., returning a small, static file)? Do you have the option of sending multiple requests in one HTTP request? That would lightly improve efficiency, but HTTP GETS are already pretty efficient.

Comment: See if it can help....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301274/node-js-is-it-possible-to-hit-1000-http-get-request-to-some-api-from-a-node-js

Comment: And you can send multiple request to a server in simultaneously!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When talking only about the network, and not about the backend and heavy request processing: a big impact by many requests has the connection reusage. Talking about `HTTP/1.*` it is a `Keep-Alive` feature. *With the `HTTP/2` [multiplexing](https://http2.github.io/faq/#why-is-http2-multiplexed) is supported per default, and allows not only the reusage, but the simultaneous usage by requests*

So making parallel 100 requests causes in NodeJS to open 100 connections, while [`require('http').globalAgent.maxSockets`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets) is set per default for `Infinity`. But when you make `N` request one after another, that means, the further requests can reuse previous connections.

But you shouldn't handle the connection pool by yourself, just set `maxSockets` to `15`, and the nodejs agent will handle it for you. *Note*: it is difficult to say what the value actually should be, but before nodes version `0.12` the default value for `maxSockets` was also `5`.