# how to make synchronous http calls within async.each in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I want to make http requests to an API-s to collect for each user it's data and insert into mongodb.

The problem I am having is, it is doing all the requests at once, and seems it gets stuck somewhere and I don't know what is going on.

Al thou I am using async library and add the request() method inside each iteration, and I dont know if this is the right way, here is the code:

```
  function iterateThruAllStudents(from, to) {
    Student.find({status: 'student'})
        .populate('user')
        .exec(function (err, students) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            async.forEach(students, function iteratee(student, callback) {
                if (student.worksnap.user != null) {
                    var options = {
                        url: 'https://api.worksnaps.com/api/projects/' + project_id + '/time_entries.xml?user_ids=' + student.worksnap.user.user_id + '&from_timestamp=' + from + '&to_timestamp=' + to,
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization': 'Basic bGhNSVJkVUFwOE1DS2loOFVyZkFyOENEZEhPSXdCdUlHdElWMHo0czo='
                        }
                    };
                    request(options, getTimeEntriesFromWorksnap);
                }
                callback(); // tell async that the iterator has completed
            }, function (err) {
                console.log('iterating done');
            });
        });
}

    function getTimeEntriesFromWorksnap(error, response, body) {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            parser.parseString(body, function (err, results) {
                var json_string = JSON.stringify(results.time_entries);
                var timeEntries = JSON.parse(json_string);
                _.forEach(timeEntries, function (timeEntry) {
                    _.forEach(timeEntry, function (item) {
                        saveTimeEntry(item);
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }

    function saveTimeEntry(item) {
        Student.findOne({
                'worksnap.user.user_id': item.user_id[0]
            })
            .populate('user')
            .exec(function (err, student) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                student.timeEntries.push(item);
                student.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('item inserted...');
                    }
                });

            });
    }

var from = new Date(startDate).getTime() / 1000;
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 30);
var to = new Date(startDate).getTime() / 1000;
iterateThruAllStudents(from, to);
```

I am new to JavaScript, especially when dealing with async.

Any help?

Comment: it's supposed to do them all at once, aync. if you don't want that, call the next() job from the previous one.

Comment: @dandavis, how do I do that?

Comment: consider an over-simplification: `var r=[1,2,3]; function next(){ var v=r.pop(); if(!v){ alert('done');}else{ console.log(v); next();}} next();`

Comment: you should be using Promise which allows async calls to be make in a linear sync sequence

Comment: @ScottStensland, could you give an an example, related to my case ? I would appreciate alot that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you missed iteratee param in the `each` method of async - `iteratee(item, callback)`. Look at this example [here](https://github.com/caolan/async#each).

You need to call `callback` each time inside your iteratee function to tell async continue doing its processing.

`each(collection, iteratee, [callback])`

- > collection - collection to iterate over.
- > iteratee(item, callback) - function to apply to each item in coll. The iteratee is passed a callback(err) which must be called once it has completed. If no error has occurred, the callback should be run without arguments or with an explicit null argument. The array index is not passed to the iteratee. If you need the index, use forEachOf.
- > callback(err) - Optional callback which is called when all iteratee functions have finished, or an error occurs.

If you need synchronous behavior, no probs! There is also `eachSeries` method with the same signature except every collection item will be iterated synchronously.

**UPDATE:**

Changes should be implemented:

Pass `async` callback:

`request(options, getTimeEntriesFromWorksnap(callback));`

Return necessary for `request` callback function:

```
function getTimeEntriesFromWorksnap(callback) {
  return function(error, response, body) { 
    // ...       
    saveTimeEntry(item, callback);                       
    // ...
  }        
}
```

Call `callback` only after record is saved in database:

```
function saveTimeEntry(item, callback) {
  // ..
  student.save(callback);
  // ..
}
```

Refactor nested loops (not sure what `timeEntries`, `timeEntry` are, so use appropriate async method to iterate these data structures):

```
async.each(timeEntries, function (timeEntry, callback) {
   async.each(timeEntry, function (item, callback) {
       saveTimeEntry(item, callback);
   }, callback);
}, callback);
```

Comment: I have updated my code, could you have a look and let me know if it's fine?

Comment: Al thou, I can still see it's kinda making async requests.... I want to go thru all student , take all date once done, continue with next one,

Comment: @HisniFazlija better, but not good yet. `request` is asynchronous, so you need to add the call of `callback()` right after response will be received (for every request witin your `async.each`). Look here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request for more details.

Comment: I dont see any option where can I add callback() func within request()... Could you give me a sample? thnx

Comment: can I do smth like this:  var r = request(options, getTimeEntriesFromWorksnap);
                        r.on('response', function(response) {
                            callback(); // tell async that the iterator has completed
                        })

Comment: I get error, saying , Callback was already called, async.js:43, after I did changes according to ur new update

Comment: @HisniFazlija ah, I see. The reason is your nested `_.forEach` inside `getTimeEntriesFromWorksnap`. You need to call callback once per iteration for the main `each` loop. In your case you need to replace these `_.forEach` loops with async methods accordingly.

Comment: I updated those _forEach to:

  async.forEach(timeEntries, function iteratee(timeEntry, callback) {
                        async.forEach(timeEntry, function iteratee(item) {
                            saveTimeEntry(item,callback);
                        });
                    });  still getting the same error

Comment: It still does not seem working....got stuck somewhere, nothing is inserting.... is there any way that I can see where is it stuck the execution?

Comment: well, I will try gathering the data for 1 day, and see if it works... maybe the json for 30 days  is too big and it get's stuck... thnx

Comment: When I try to print console.log(response.statusCode); within getTimeEntriesFromWorksnap(callback), I can see it being displayed lots of time at once, which means it is making lots of calls at once, right? Which I would want one call at a time...

Comment: ok, I have been waiting for almost a hour to see what's happening after that stuck state, and I see it has return this:
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory

Answer (score 2):

Use `Async.eachLimit()` to make batched request to the api...Try this `iterateThruAllStudents()` function.

I already had same question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301274/node-js-is-it-possible-to-hit-1000-http-get-request-to-some-api-from-a-node-js)

See tutorial of limiting [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#forEachOf).
Though i am making the limit as 5 but you can do whatever you want(10,50 etc).

```
function iterateThruAllStudents(from, to) {
  Student.find({status: 'student'})
    .populate('user')
    .exec(function (err, students) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      async.eachLimit(students,5,function iteratee(student, callback) {
        if (student.worksnap.user != null) {
          var options = {
            url: 'https://api.worksnaps.com/api/projects/' + project_id + '/time_entries.xml?user_ids=' + student.worksnap.user.user_id + '&from_timestamp=' + from + '&to_timestamp=' + to,
            headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Basic bGhNSVJkVUFwOE1DS2loOFVyZkFyOENEZEhPSXdCdUlHdElWMHo0czo='
            }
          };
          request(options,getTimeEntriesFromWorksnap(callback));
        }
      }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log('iterating done');
      });
    });
}

function getTimeEntriesFromWorksnap(cb) {
  return function(error, response, body){
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      parser.parseString(body, function (err, results) {
        var json_string = JSON.stringify(results.time_entries);
        var timeEntries = JSON.parse(json_string);
        async.each(timeEntries,function(timeEntry,cb1){
          async.each(timeEntry,function(item,cb2){
            saveTimeEntry(item,cb2);
          },function(err){
            if(err)
              cb1(err);
            else
              cb1();
          })
        },function(err){
          if(err)
            cb(err);
          else
            cb();
        });
        //_.forEach(timeEntries, function (timeEntry) {
        //  _.forEach(timeEntry, function (item) {
        //    saveTimeEntry(item);
        //  });
        //});
      });
    }
    cb(null);
  }
}

function saveTimeEntry(item,cb2) {
  Student.findOne({
      'worksnap.user.user_id': item.user_id[0]
    })
    .populate('user')
    .exec(function (err, student) {
      if (err) {
        return cb2(err);
      }
      student.timeEntries.push(item);
      student.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          //return cb2(err);//Do it if you wanna throw an error.
        } else {
          console.log('item inserted...');
        }
        cb2();
      });
    });
}

var from = new Date(startDate).getTime() / 1000;
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 30);
var to = new Date(startDate).getTime() / 1000;
iterateThruAllStudents(from, to);
```

Comment: Could I know, what is that 5 for, within eachLimit function? thnx

Comment: the requests will be hit 5 at a time and after successfull completion of these 5's nest 5 will be hit!!!

Comment: see async.eachLimit() usage for more detail...i added the link

Comment: this is not working either :s... at some point after a while it stops inserting data into db...

Comment: This is happening due to asynchronous call in saveEntryTime();

Comment: To be honest I like your solution best, how do I change that also saveEntryTime would be synchronous???

Comment: What do u want to achieve here?