# How to trace uncaughtException exception in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, uncaught-exception

How do I find out where that error is originated from ? The error output doesn't look very descriptive. From the log, it was `ECONNRESET` error.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {

})
```

Comment: The best start would be to stop using `uncaughtException` handlers and properly handle all errors in your callbacks and promises.

Comment: @RobertRossmann is there any other alternative for debugging? It usually happens after the app rests for a while.

Comment: Maybe here is one useful link, [configure Node to dump core on an uncaught exception](http://www.joyent.com/developers/node/debug#postmortem)

Comment: @TuanAnhTran handling errors **is** debugging. Trust me, if you do not handle errors today, you should immediately start doing so. Otherwise your app will never be stable, it will always crash with the most unexpected reasons and you will have no clue where that came from.

Comment: @RobertRossmann thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.

What made it hard, is it's not in my code, but in a library i use.

So as you also have found out, the stack trace provided isn't helpful at all.  Even after installing a package like `longjohn` your stack track from this server crash is all internal:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27)
---------------------------------------------
    at _destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:34:15)
    at Socket._destroy (net.js:607:3)
    at Socket.destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:32:8)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:19)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

You need to handle the `emitter.on("error")` events, as basically described here: [Node js ECONNRESET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset)

In my situation I was able to reproduce the error by sending an invalid password via a `curl` request.   and was able to solve because the library I'm uses exposes the `request` object for incoming requests.

So with that, here's my solution code:

```js
function onRequest(requestDetails){
            requestDetails.request.connection.on( "error", ( _err ) => {
                log.error( "request.connection.on.error", _err );
            } );

            let reqSocket = requestDetails.request.socket;
            reqSocket.on( "error", ( _err ) => {
                log.error( "request.socket.on.error", _err );
                reqSocket.destroy( _err );
            } );

            requestDetails.request.on( "error", ( _err ) => {
                log.error( "request.on.error", _err );
            } );

            // my actual request handling code goes here.....
}
```

I also added error handler for the `server` object, though that wasn't needed in this case:

```js
    server.on( 'requestFailed', ( { request, error }: any ) => {
        log.error( `Request ${ request.url } failed`, error );
    } );

    server.on( 'error', ( ...args: any[] ) => {
        log.error( "server.on.error", args );
    } );

    server.on( 'connection', function ( socket ) {
        socket.on( 'error', function ( err ) {
            log.error( "Client socket error:", err );
            socket.destroy( err );
        } );
    } );
```