# NodeJS Request throw [Error: read ECONNRESET] when make http call

Tags: node.js, http, request

when use Request TCP always REST, but use node native http module is fine.

```
var request = require('request');
var http = require('http');

request.get('http://www.drcnet.com.cn/www/integrated/login.ashx',function(err, res,body){

console.log(err, res); //  [Error: read ECONNRESET] 

});

http.get('http://www.drcnet.com.cn/www/integrated/login.ashx', function(res) {

console.log(res.statusCode); // 200 all right

})
```

how to fixed it ?

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset

Comment: but it's not my site, i just try to crawl conent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
request.get('http://www.drcnet.com.cn/www/integrated/login.ashx',
    {
        originalHostHeaderName: 'Host'
    },
    function(err, res,body){
        console.log(err, res); 
    }
);
```

this site header 'Host' must be Initials.

http module use 'Host' as default, but request module use 'host'