# Make HTTP GET request using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make an HTTP GET request using Node.js but it errors

> Request to '/path/to/file?query=string' failed: read ECONNRESET

How may I fix it? Thanks in advance. It was working before, I'm not sure of what changed.

```
var http = require("http");
var data = "";

var options = {
    host: "sub.example.com",
    port: 80,
    path: "/path/to/file?query=string",
    method: "GET",
};

var req = http.request(options, function(resp){
    resp.on('data', function(_data){data = data + _data});
    resp.on('end', function(){callback(data)})
});

req.on('error',function(e){
    console.log("Request to '" + filename + "' failed: " + e.message)
});

req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

Comment: Likely duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GET` requests typically do not have a body. Try removing the `req.write()` lines and you may have better luck.

Comment: I believe it worked, but I'm not sure if before the server was just overfloading.