# What is the default timeout for NPM request module (REST client)?

Tags: node.js, rest, npm, timeout

Following will be my node.js call to retrive some data, which is taking more than 1 minute. Here this will be timeout at 1 minute (60 seconds). I put a console log for the latency also. However I have configured the timeout for 120 seconds but it is not reflecting. I know the default level nodejs server timeout is 120 seconds but still I get the timeout (of 60 seconds) from this [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module for this call. Please provide your insights on this.

```
var options = {
  method: 'post',
  url:url,
  timeout: 120000,
  json: true,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-Authorization": "abc",
    "Accept-Encoding":"gzip"
  }
}
var startTime = new Date();
request(options, function(e, r, body) {
  var endTime = new Date();
  var latencyTime = endTime - startTime;
  console.log("Ended. latencyTime:"+latencyTime/1000);
  res.status(200).send(body);

});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [request options docs](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback), scrolling down to the `timeout` entry:

> **timeout** - Integer containing the number of milliseconds to wait for a server to send response headers (and start the response body) before aborting the request. Note that if the underlying TCP connection cannot be established, the OS-wide TCP connection timeout will overrule the timeout option (the default in Linux can be anywhere from 20-120 seconds).

Note the last part "if the underlying TCP connection cannot be established, the OS-wide TCP connection timeout will overrule the timeout option".

There is also an entire section on [Timeouts](https://github.com/request/request#timeouts).  Based on that, and your code sample, we can modify the request sample as such

```
request(options, function(e, r, body) {
  if (e.code === 'ETIMEDOUT' && e.connect === true){
  // when there's a timeout and connect is true, we're meeting the
  // conditions described for the timeout option where the OS governs
  console.log('bummer');
  }
});
```

If this is true, you'll need to decide if changing OS settings is possible and acceptable (this is beyond the scope of this answer and such a question would be better on Server Fault).

Comment: Hi Matthew, I'm getting this error. { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }. Any thoughts why I'm getting this ?. Through a REST client (POSTMAN/ etc) I was able to get the response within 1 second. But through this node module it takes some time. And when I cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syn_retries 
I got the value of 6.

Comment: First, if `ECONNRESET` is the error then the timeout isn't the problem.  You have a different issue and you should see this other Stack Overflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17637900/2247344

Comment: Is this answer still correct?  When I try to use it, or any of the options, the e or error parameter never contains a code property or connect property.  It does contain a message that says timeout

Comment: I haven't used request in a few months, but the documentation is consistent with this answer.  So I can't say for certain, but it seems the module is still built this way (or has changed but docs aren't updated?).