# express.js app is crashing out after some time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

It's a super simple express app. After some time WITH NOT REQUESTS, just sitting idle this error will happen:

```
Example app listening on port 80!
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:572:26)
```

For reference here is the code

```
"use strict"

var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.end('hello')
})

app.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 80!')
})
```

Comment: How do you know that there are no requests? You are not logging anything

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset Maybe this can help?

Comment: Its running on my local machine and I'm not hitting it.

Comment: Does your local machine have a conflicting web server running on the same port, or some security application which shuts down your node process?

Answer (score 1):

socket receive a 'error' event,we should use 'error' event listener, otherwise it will propagate and crash you process.

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){ ... ... });
server.on('error', function(err) { ... ... });
server.on('listening', function(err) { ... ... });
```

Comment: I'm using expressjs not http.server