# Getting error after running "npm install"

Tags: node.js

I've installed the latest version of Node.js and it works fine when I try to get the version in CMD but when I write npm install or any other installation command it gives error.

[image]

Comment: 1) don't post pictures of text. 2) did you even investigate the connection problem ?

Comment: Did you get this resolved, @DN-JAVA?

Answer (score 0):

That's a connection issue. Ensure you have internet access and that your not behind a proxy that could be blocking npm.

## Options to Resolve

**1. SSL issue.**

Use: `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

So that npm looks for the `http` version, rather then the `https` site. You should then be able to use `npm install` as normal

**2. Proxy Issue**

Check your npm proxy settings, and consider removing it. Run:

```
npm config get proxy
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

**3. Sudo Issue**

*(answer by [Kevin Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/763231/kevin-cooper))*

This can be caused by installing anything with npm using sudo -- this causes the files in the cache to be owned by root, resulting in this problem. You can fix it by running:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.npm
```

to remove the cache. Then try whatever you were doing again, making sure you never use sudo along with npm (or the problem may come back).

Lots more information: [NPM throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo/24404451#24404451)

**4. Actual NPM Issue**

This is the least likley, but it is worth checking there are no open issues relating to this at the moment.

This issue resulted in a similar problem to you had: 
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9418

Finally, since this is quite a common error message, take a look at other StackOverflow and web results. This one especially may help, [Node js ECONNRESET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset)