# Connect to Cosmos Graph DB through NodeJs

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb, azure-emulator

I want to connect into the cosmos graph db in NodeJs. The implemented sample is coming from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-graph-nodejs). I've changed the example to connect into the emulator like the following:

```
var Gremlin = require("gremlin-secure");

const client = Gremlin.createClient(
    8081,
    "localhost", // or 127.0.0.1
    {
        "session": false,
        "ssl": false,
        "user": "/dbs/graphdb/colls/graphcollz",
        "password": "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw=="  
    });

console.log('Running Drop');
client.on('error', (err) => {
     console.log(err.message);
});
```

I should mention that in the above documentation mentioned that:

> The Gremlin endpoint must be only the host name without the protocol/port number, like mygraphdb.graphs.azure.com (not https://mygraphdb.graphs.azure.com or mygraphdb.graphs.azure.com:433).

Hence, the endpoint address for db is `localhost` without any protocol/port.
Also, ssl is set to `false` to prevent "self signed certificate" error, and graphdb and graphcollz were created before in emulator.

In this way, I've gotten the following error when try to execute the following query:

```
client.execute('g.V().drop()', {}, (err, results) => {
     if (err) return console.error(err);
     console.log(results);
});
```

The error is:

> read ECONNRESET

Also, [Node js ECONNRESET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset) post cannot help to solve the problem to connect into the emulator.

Now, the **question** is how can I connect into the cosmos graph db emulator through the NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

The CosmosDB Emulator only emulates the DocumentDb endpoint. You can use the emulator with the .NET GraphDb SDK, but not the Node gremlin-secure module.

Here is the difference:

The .NET GraphDb SDK translates the Gremlin query to a DocumentDb query on the client side. It then calls the DocumentDb endpoint in Azure (your-site.documents.azure.com).

The Node GraphDb SDK sends the Gremlin query, as a string, to a GraphDB endpoint in Azure (your-site.graphs.azure.com). This endpoint appears to run code similar to the .NET SDK, but on the server side, translating the Gremlin query to a DocumentDb query.

Edit: Looks like Azure added a blurb on the [emulator page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator) that states they aren't currently supporting graphdb and tables. Nevertheless, I believe my answer is still correct: you could use the .NET GraphDB SDK and the emulator. (but the product is pre-release, so this may also be subject to change...):

[image]

Comment: Anyhow, I need connect to the GraphDB through NodeJs. Therefore, .NET SDK does not work for me. Also, I used it before, and approve your post on translation of the graph query into the document DB query.