# Javascript Websocket Close = Server crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Hi was trying to send some data back and forth, and I found out that when I closed my client my server crashed...

My Server is Node.JS using the nodejs-websocket library.

Then I found out you had to add this.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    connection.close()
}
```

Is there away around this?
 Because if someone wanted to crash your server couldn't he just remove that 
 from the JavaScript?

Please keep in mind this is my first time using websockets

Server Side:

```
var ws = require("nodejs-websocket");
var server = ws.createServer(function(conn){
        console.log("New connection")


        conn.on("end", function(code,reason){
            console.log('Connection Lost')
        });
}).listen(8001);
```

Error:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:568:26)
```

Comment: Show your serverside code maybe...

Comment: Uhhh, the problem here is in your server-side code so we need to see that in order to offer you some help.

Comment: Just updated now.

Comment: What does your server output looks like when it shuts down? I can't imagine there not being any error messages that you could share with us.

Comment: @workaholic_gangster911
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:568:26)

Comment: Can you post line 160 please?

Comment: @workaholic_gangster911 that's line 160 of some internal Node.js file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may just have to listen to connection error events on your socket, and it won't throw an exception (and close your app). At least that's what this answer says:
[Node js ECONNRESET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset)

Basically, try this first:

```
var ws = require("nodejs-websocket");
var server = ws.createServer(function(conn){
        console.log("New connection");

        conn.on("error", function(err) {
            console.log("Error caught: ")
            console.log(err.stack)
        });

        conn.on("end", function(code,reason){
            console.log('Connection Lost')
        });
}).listen(8001);
```

Comment: The server instance itself may also emit `error` events (https://github.com/sitegui/nodejs-websocket#event-errorerrobj)

Comment: Sometimes the answer is just too damm simple! You right thank you!