# How to brusquely drop a Websocket connection in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket

I am seeing this error sometimes https://stackoverflow.com/a/17637900/135829, and added a handler to backend side for error case, which I want to test.

For that I want to drop the connection in Chrome. I have access to connection instance, but running `.close()` method doesn't cause the error as it closes the connection gently.

How can I drop it harshly like it's an error?

Comment: What happens if you close the browser from **X** or even terminate the browser process ? Is the connection closed gently again ?

Comment: absolutely, no errors. As described in the related thread, it happens randomly from time to time.