# Nodejs server stop with error

Tags: node.js, express

My server stops with this error how can i solve it? Or what it is?
events.js:182
     throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
     ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
   at exports._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
   at TCP.onread (net.js:610:25)

Thanks for answers

Comment: You have to provide more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "ECONNRESET" means the other side of the TCP conversation abruptly closed its end of the connection. This is most probably due to one or more application protocol errors. You could look at the API server logs to see if it complains about something.

To know more about `ECONNRESET`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17637900/3300806).

The message `Unhandled 'error' event` is suggesting that you are not listening for the `error` event in your code. 
You can catch errors like these by catching the `error` event like the following

```
connection.on("error", function(err){ // handle "error" event so nodejs will not crash
    console.log(err);
});
```