# Azure Service Bus Unknown Error code ECONNRESET

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

We are using NodeJS SDK for reading messages, pushing message in ServiceBusQueue in Azure since past few months.

We have started facing an exception "`ECONNRESET`" while reading and pushing message in the SericeBusQueue with the frequency of every 3-4 minutes.

```
{"code" : "ECONNRESET",
"errno" : "ECONNRESET",
"syscall" : "read"}
```

We were facing the same issue in the early days also, but it was once in days.

Comment: Have you seen this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset ? What are you asking here ? Could you show us your code please

Comment: @Thomas I have seen this post. we are getting this error when we make a call for pushing and reading messages in service bus queue only.