# Node js ECONNRESET events.js:72 throw er

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

Hello I am working on Node js sockets. I am listening data from multiple devices through ip and port. After running for a while I get this exception and my program stops

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:559:19)
```

This is the code I have written

```
var net = require('net');
var request = require('request');



var net = require('net');
var HOST = '172.xx.x.xx';
var PORT = 52xx;
var cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // Fork workers.
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('death', function(worker) {
        console.log('worker ' + worker.pid + ' died');
        cluster.fork();
    });
} else {
    net.createServer(function(socket){
         console.log('received connection...');
        socket.on('data', function(data) {

            var options = {
  uri: 'http://demourl/api',
  method: 'POST',
  body: {
    message:data.toString()
  },
  json: true 

};
             console.log(data.toString());

             request(options, function (error, response, body) {

});

        });


    }).listen(PORT, HOST);
}
```

How can I catch an error and prevent my program from stopping.

Comment: use `socket.on("error", (err) =>
    console.log("socket error: ")
    console.log(err.stack);
    socket.destroy();
  )` and

Comment: @itaintme could you please tell me where should I insert this code in my code. I am getting an error. I think I may be putting at the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include `socket.on("error", ...` like this. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset)

```
socket.on("error", (err) =>
    console.log("socket error: ")
    console.log(err.stack);
    socket.destroy();
)
```

Comment: could you please tell me where should I insert this code in my code. I am getting an error. I think I may be putting at the wrong place?

Comment: @user1hjgjhgjhggjhg inside `net.createServer(...` Did you check out the other so link I posted in my answer?