# "TSocket read 0 bytes" during a long running Hive insert query

Tags: python, hive, thrift, pyhive

I'm running a long-ish insert query in Hive using PyHive 0.6.1 and it fails with `thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes` after about 5 minutes running. On the server side the query keeps running until finishing successfully. I don't have this problem with fast queries.

I can't reproduce it locally on my Mac with the same python version: the code correctly waits untill the query finishes. The environment in which this happens is a Docker container based on python:3.6-slim. Among other things, i'm installing libsasl2-dev and libsasl2-modules packages, and pyhive[hive] python package.

Any clue why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

The code i'm using is:

```
import contextlib
from pyhive.hive import connect

def get_conn():
    return connect(
        host='my-host',
        port=10000,
        auth='NONE',
        username='username',
        database='database'
    )

with contextlib.closing(get_conn()) as conn, \
        contextlib.closing(conn.cursor()) as cur:
    cur.execute('My long insert statement')
```

This is the full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 364, in execute
    response = self._connection.client.ExecuteStatement(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/TCLIService/TCLIService.py", line 280, in ExecuteStatement
    return self.recv_ExecuteStatement()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/TCLIService/TCLIService.py", line 292, in recv_ExecuteStatement
    (fname, mtype, rseqid) = iprot.readMessageBegin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py", line 134, in readMessageBegin
    sz = self.readI32()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py", line 217, in readI32
    buff = self.trans.readAll(4)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 60, in readAll
    chunk = self.read(sz - have)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thrift_sasl/__init__.py", line 166, in read
    self._read_frame()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thrift_sasl/__init__.py", line 170, in _read_frame
    header = self._trans.readAll(4)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 60, in readAll
    chunk = self.read(sz - have)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 132, in read
    message='TSocket read 0 bytes')
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 185, in __exit__
    self.thing.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 221, in close
    response = self._client.CloseSession(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/TCLIService/TCLIService.py", line 218, in CloseSession
    return self.recv_CloseSession()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/TCLIService/TCLIService.py", line 230, in recv_CloseSession
    (fname, mtype, rseqid) = iprot.readMessageBegin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py", line 134, in readMessageBegin
    sz = self.readI32()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py", line 217, in readI32
    buff = self.trans.readAll(4)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 60, in readAll
    chunk = self.read(sz - have)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thrift_sasl/__init__.py", line 166, in read
    self._read_frame()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thrift_sasl/__init__.py", line 170, in _read_frame
    header = self._trans.readAll(4)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 60, in readAll
    chunk = self.read(sz - have)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 132, in read
    message='TSocket read 0 bytes')
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

The code raised exception is below:

```
  def read(self, sz):
        try:
            buff = self.handle.recv(sz)
        except socket.error as e:
            if (e.args[0] == errno.ECONNRESET and
                    (sys.platform == 'darwin' or sys.platform.startswith('freebsd'))):
                # freebsd and Mach don't follow POSIX semantic of recv
                # and fail with ECONNRESET if peer performed shutdown.
                # See corresponding comment and code in TSocket::read()
                # in lib/cpp/src/transport/TSocket.cpp.
                self.close()
                # Trigger the check to raise the END_OF_FILE exception below.
                buff = ''
            else:
                raise
        if len(buff) == 0:
            raise TTransportException(type=TTransportException.END_OF_FILE,
                                      message='TSocket read 0 bytes')
        return buff
```

I think it may raised by meeting `errno.ECONNRESET` error which could happens when the server deliberately close the connection. (According to this [node-js-econnreset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset), the server may kill the connection when it is too busy and found the connect is over 'keep-alive' timeout)

You may check your server's log and find whether there exists some kind of killing connection behavior.

I am not sure about it, just providing my thinking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I checked this code also, problem is this happens inside a Debian based docker container (`sys.platform` is `'linux'`), so it actually could not enter into that if statement. Furthermore, locally on my mac (with `sys.platform=='darwin'`) everything works just fine.

I suspect that this is some client side error, timeout of some kind, but i i can't find out what it can be.