# read:ECONNRESET with Axios

Tags: axios

I've encountered read:ECONNRESET error while I was trying to some data through axios post.

A configuration for Axios is

```
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const axios = require('axios').create({
    //keepAlive pools and reuses TCP connections, so it's faster
    httpAgent: new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
});
```

function to send post request is

```
axios.post(`${HOST}/sendEmail/`, qs.stringify(params))
                        .then(() => {
                            if (conversation.managerUnreadCount) {
                                console.log('[todo] conversation.managerUnreadCount ', conversation.managerUnreadCount);

                            }
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.error('err in axios', err, url);
                        });
```

Error is below..

```
{ Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:580:26)
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  config: 
   { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
     transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
     timeout: 0,
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     headers: 
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.16.2',
        'Content-Length': 737 },
     httpAgent: 
      Agent {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 80,
        protocol: 'http:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: {},
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: true,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256 },
     httpsAgent: 
      Agent {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 443,
        protocol: 'https:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        freeSockets: [Object],
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: true,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256,
        maxCachedSessions: 100,
        _sessionCache: [Object] },
     method: 'post',
     url: 'https://us-central1-customurl.cloudfunctions.net/sendEmail/',
     data: 'fromEmail=testerA11%40mailinator.com&fromEmailName=tester%20A11&replyTo=testerA11%40msg.dev.hostthere.email&replyToName=tester%20A11&toEmail=hostthere.auth.test%40gmail.com&subject=test%20...*(custom data string here)*' },
  request: 
   Writable {
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { response: [Function: handleResponse],
        error: [Function: handleRequestError] },
     _eventsCount: 2,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _options: 
      { protocol: 'https:',
        maxRedirects: 21,
        maxBodyLength: 10485760,
        hostname: 'us-central1-customurl.cloudfunctions.net',
        port: null,
        path: '/sendEmail/',
        method: 'post',
        headers: [Object],
        agent: [Object],
        auth: undefined,
        nativeProtocols: [Object],
        pathname: '/sendEmail/' },
     _redirectCount: 0,
     _redirects: [],
     _requestBodyLength: 737,
     _requestBodyBuffers: [ [Object] ],
     _onNativeResponse: [Function],
     _currentRequest: 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedHeader: [Object],
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        _header: 'POST /sendEmail/ HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.16.2\r\nContent-Length: 737\r\nHost: us-central1-customurl.cloudfunctions.net\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: null,
        agent: [Object],
... }
```

And in my system many different post requests are made at same time.
(not same url with above)

I thought if I added keep-alive options where axios created, but it did not help.

Any other ideas to resolve this error?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: The problem same as node ECONNRESET, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17637900/10861398

Comment: Connected with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60370389/how-to-handle-socket-hangup-error-in-nodejs-using-axios/68584379#68584379

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Turns out I was running script from a local machine that had intermittent Internet connection. Fixing the connection solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

check error log at api side.
In my case, it was error from api side which was throwing exception and its leading to this error.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are not handling the error in your host server.