# How to handle socket hangup error in NodeJs using Axios

Tags: node.js, typescript, post, axios

I am using Axios to call a post API from nodejs. Sometimes it is throwing socket hangup error.
I have seen solutions for this issue like, catch this error and retry the request again.
But since it is a post request for updating some details in DB, we cant hit it again.

```
  const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    });

const response = await axios({
      url,
      method: Constants.POST,
      data,
      httpsAgent,
      proxy: false,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: bearerToken
      }
    });
```

> Error we are getting is : socket hang up

Do anyone have idea about how to resolve this issue?

We have created this nodejs code as a Lambda in aws and the API we are calling is in EC2 server.

Comment: Is the server on the other end yours?  Or someone else's?  If it's yours, I would say that you should first figure out why you're getting hangups and attempt to fix that.  Then, you could implement some sort of client-generated `postID` to prevent duplicate posts upon retry.

Comment: Then, time to do some debugging on the target server and figure out why it's dropping your connection.  Possible timeout either in server or in AWS infrastructure?  Failure to always send a response?  Improper error handling?  Could be lots of things.

Comment: hi @jfriend00 , Server is ours only. Its a Spring rest controller with Application scoped.

Comment: No, Its one or two times in a 500 request having this failure. Not sure is this an AWS issue or API load handling issue

Comment: Well, you either have to fix the hangup issue or you need to implement client retry that is probably protected from duplication with some sort of request-specific, client-generated ID as part of every request (so the server can tell if it's a duplicate POST).  I would think you could implement some diagnostics on the target server that track when a hangup occurs before you intended for the socket to close and try to get some data on when/why it's happening.

Answer (score 6):

I checked that key option is `keepAlive: true` for "https.Agent"

Try to use

```
const client = axios.create({
    timeout: 60000,
    maxContentLength: 500 * 1000 * 1000,
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
})
```

instead of  default  `axios`.