# Node Js mysql(and mysql2) ECONNRESET

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mysql2

i am currently trying to connect to a MySQL server on the internet using Node.Js with the `mysql` or the `mysql2` NPM dependencies to use queries and other related stuff.

the code is simple...

```
//i import my dependency
const mysql = require('mysql2') //either 'mysql' or 'mysql2'

//i create my pool to create connections as needed
var conn = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'some_database_i_have_access_to.mysql.uhserver.com',
    user: 'valid_user',
    password: 'valid_password',
    database: 'some_existing_database'
})

//i try to connect (this is the part where it fails)
conn.getConnection((err,conn) => {
    if (err) throw err //<- the error is thrown here

    //i do query stuff
    conn.query("SELECT * FROM atable",(err,res,firlds) => {
        if(err) throw err
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
    })
    //i close the connection
    conn.end()
})
```

yet i always get an Error like this:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\Aluno\Desktop\my-project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\Aluno\Desktop\my-project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Users\Aluno\Desktop\my-project\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:118:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aluno\Desktop\my-project\private\dtp-mysql.js:13:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:536:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:17)
```

all i know about the error is that the connection abruptly closes in one of the sides as stated in this question ([Node js ECONNRESET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset)), but nothing more, and creating singular connections does not solve this issue for me either.

any fixes to that?

Comment: you can also ref below url.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586818/error-while-inserting-large-volume-data-in-mysql-by-using-node-js-error-code

Answer (score 1):

you can also ref below url.
[error while inserting LARGE volume data in mysql by using node.js （error code: 'ECONNRESET'）](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586818/error-while-inserting-large-volume-data-in-mysql-by-using-node-js-error-code)

I have fixed this issue. It is caused by the default definition max_allowed_packet. Find max_allowed_packet in my.ini (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7). Update to 'max_allowed_packet=64M'. Restart mysql. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know this was asked some time ago, but is it possibly because you're using:

> conn.end()

Since you're using a Pooled connection, I think you can release the connection using

```
conn.release()
```

Or

```
conn.destroy()
```