# error while inserting LARGE volume data in mysql by using node.js （error code: 'ECONNRESET'）

Tags: mysql, node.js

I met an error while inserting large volume data in mysql by using node.js
Here is the data

```
instData = [ [ '73caf3d0-f6a4-11e8-8160-eb5f91ce3830',
               '20181017'],
             [ '73caf3d1-f6a4-11e8-8160-eb5f91ce3830',
               '20181019'],
            ... 49316 more items ]
```

Here is part of connection code:

```
 let pool = mysql.createPool(db);

 module.exports = {
   connPool (sql, val, cb) {  //function name
       pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
         if(err){
           console.log('Connection Error:' + err);
         }else{
           console.log('allConnections:' + pool._allConnections.length);
           let q = conn.query(sql, val, (err, rows,fields) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log('Query:' + sql + ' error:' + err);
              }
              cb(err, rows, fields);
              conn.release();
            });
         } // end if
      }); // end pool.getConnection
   }, 
  ......
```

When I run the insert the code, I got the error.

```
 sql_inst ='insert into demo (id,upload_time) values ?';
 func.connPool(sql_inst, [instData], (err,rows,fields) => {
    if(err==null){
        res.json({code: 200, msg: 'success', data: req.body });
    } else {
        res.json({code: 400, msg: 'failed:'+err});
    }
 });
```

Error info:

```
{ Error: read ECONNRESET
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (D:\Projects\test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
at PoolConnection.query (D:\Projects\test\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:200:25)
at pool.getConnection (D:\Projects\test\sql\func.js:29:26)
at Ping.onOperationComplete (D:\Projects\test\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:110:5)
at Ping.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\test\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:502:10)
at Ping._callback (D:\Projects\test\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:468:16)
at Ping.Sequence.end (D:\Projects\test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
at Ping.Sequence.OkPacket (D:\Projects\test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:92:8)
at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\Projects\vutest\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:278:23)
at Parser.write (D:\Projects\test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
errno: 'ECONNRESET',
code: 'ECONNRESET',
syscall: 'read',
fatal: true }
```

It seems the connection is closed, but the question is i use connection pool, it should not connect everytime.

When I reduce the size of data, f.g. the data contains 100 records, the code runs successfully.

Running env:
node：v10.11.0
mysql:v5.7

How cold I address this issue?
Great thx!

Comment: Work around node issue if you do not feel like using pools: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-nodejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. It is caused by the default definition max_allowed_packet.
Find max_allowed_packet in my.ini (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7).
Update to 'max_allowed_packet=64M'.
Restart mysql. 
Done.