# ECONNRESET error crashing NodeJS application

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

I am kind of new to coding and I needed some help with one error that I'm getting.

I'm running a NodeJS application (a Discord.js bot), my bot has the function to register a user's ID to a MySQL database when the user types a certain command. Sometimes it works just fine, but other times it crashes with an `ECONNRESET` error:

```js
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._handleProtocolError (C:\Users\Celeron\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:423:8)
    at Protocol.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Protocol._delegateError (C:\Users\Celeron\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:398:10)
    at Protocol.handleNetworkError (C:\Users\Celeron\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:371:10)
    at Connection._handleNetworkError (C:\Users\Celeron\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:418:18)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  fatal: true
}
```

Comment: Down-voted because this question does not provide minimal reproducible code; the debugging details is also an image and not copy-pasted. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JonathanRosa thanks for the info, I edited my post but the code is not in the format it should be.....

Comment: I had removed the down-vote and submitted an edit to fix the format.

Comment: You may want to check this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52978278/node-js-mysqland-mysql2-econnreset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should `catch` the error, so you app can handle it properly and doesn't crash when mysql connection is closed for any odd reason. Try either with `connection.on('error', ...)` or with [try-catch blocks](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_propagation_and_interception).

For keeping an open connection, you should either reconnect on close. Or simply use mysql's [pooling connection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections), which handles automatic reconnection very well, with a single code change.

PS: Pooling multiple connections is a generally good idea for async apps, like servers, but it's safe to maintain a single connection via pooling (`connectionLimit : 1`) just for automatic reconnection itself.

PPS: Mysql's inactivity timeout can be configured in server's `my.cnf`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem.
The crash happened because of the application inactivity on the database, and when the con. becomes inactive for a couple seconds the mysql server closes de connection making the bot to crash when the code requires some database resource.

The solution was to create a function to keep constant activity in the DB connection.

Here is the code:

````
    con.query('SELECT 1', (err) => {
        if (err) throw err

        console.log('Tum tum')  \\ Heartbeat noises to know if it worked xD
    })
}
setInterval(keepAlive, 15000)```
````

Comment: I don't find this the very best solution, mainly because your app will still crash when it loses mysql connection for other reasons. See my answer below.

Comment: @dayvee.cz Your response indeed is much more optimal, keeping a connection open during the whole proccess brings up space for tons of errors.