# Getting error while NodeJs Azure Mysql connection

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, azure, azureportal

I am getting this error while connecting to "azure mysql" database using "mysql" package in nodejs.

> Error: read ECONNRESET                                                                                                      at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)                                                            --------------------                                                                                                    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\AMEY\Documents\MCA Projects\Email Portal\email-portal-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:141:48)                                                                                                at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\AMEY\Documents\MCA Projects\Email Portal\email-portal-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:41)                                                                                                at Connection.connect (C:\Users\AMEY\Documents\MCA Projects\Email Portal\email-portal-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:130:18)                                                                                                      at Object. (C:\Users\AMEY\Documents\MCA Projects\Email Portal\email-portal-backend\index.js:52:7)            at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)                                                             at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)                                               at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)                                                                  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)                                                        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)                                     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {                                                                           errno: -4077,                                                                                                           code: 'ECONNRESET',                                                                                                     syscall: 'read',                                                                                                        fatal: true                                                                                                           }

Here's my code with createConnection:

```
const conn2 = new mysql.createConnection({
    host: "*****.database.windows.net",
    port: 1433,
    user: "ameykhoje",
    password: "******",
    database: "dbname",
    ssl: true,
    debug: true })
conn2.connect((err) => {
if(err) {
    console.log(err)
}
else {
    console.log("connected to azure")
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Connected to database`);
    });
}})
```

I have tried same this with createPool also. But didn't worked.

i have also updated mysql package in package.json to:

```
"mysql": "git://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#e3e123e9af7c0829a6c1417d911572a75b4a5f95"
```

Please help me to solve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ECONNRESET error crashing NodeJS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62416274/econnreset-error-crashing-nodejs-application)

Comment: [Nothing here?](https://www.google.com/search?q=ECONNRESET+azure+site:stackoverflow.com) or [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=read+ECONNRESET+at+TCP.onStreamRead+site:stackoverflow.com) - please always start by googling the error

Comment: I have tried but don't know why getting this error. I can connect to my local mysql db, but when i try to connect to azure it throws this error.

Comment: Are you connecting to a MySQL database or SQL database?

Comment: SQL Databases..

Comment: Then why are you using `mysql` node package? Shouldn't you be using `mssql` package?

Answer (score 0):

It seems more like your DB is not allowing access, have you tried to check the ACL on Azure to ensure you are allowing connections from your host?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is coming because of incorrect node package. You're using [`mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) node package to connect to an Azure SQL database.

You will need to use [`mssql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) node package.