# micropython http request on wemos d1 mini

Tags: httprequest, micropython

I have a micropython-running Wemos D1 mini project board.

I am trying to send a simple HTTP request on another Wemos D1 mini running Easyesp, that has a relay attached to it on pin 5. The request works like this

```
http://192.168.1.102/control?cmd=GPIO,5,1 # turns relay on
http://192.168.1.102/control?cmd=GPIO,5,1 # turns relay off
```

I have had the wemos that controls the relay working with 0 trouble for past 6 months and i can use it with my smartphone/pc browser with no trouble.

When i run my micropython script, it freezes after 3rd button press to
    `<Response object at 3fff3580>`
or i get a `ERRCONNRESET` error.

https://pastebin.com/uHQHpj1Z

I think i need to give some time for the wifi modem to do it's job?

Comment: It would be better if you post the code snippet with the question it self

Answer (score 1):

`<Response object at 3fff3580>` is the response object send back from the other Wemos. 
change
`urequests.get("http://192.168.1.102/control?cmd=GPIO,5,1")` and
`urequests.get("http://192.168.1.102/control?cmd=GPIO,5,0")` to

`res = urequests.get("http://192.168.1.102/control?cmd=GPIO,5,1")`

`res = urequests.get("http://192.168.1.102/control?cmd=GPIO,5,0")`

You can also check whether the request was success full or not by checking the status code.

You can find details about `ERRCONNRESET` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17637900/4743730)