# Nodejs throw error write ECONNRESET. what is the reason?

Tags: node.js, econnreset

Almost once every week I get this error from the nodejs server:

```
Error: write ECONNRESET
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:87:16)
    at handleWriteReq (internal/stream_base_commons.js:56:21)
    at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:139:15)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:770:11)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._write (net.js:782:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:431:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:415:5)
    at TLSSocket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:305:11)
    at abortConnection (/home/armweb/www/node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js:509:12)
    at /home/armweb/www/node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js:356:7 {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

what is the reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/how-do-i-debug-error-econnreset-in-node-js

Comment: are you using nodemon for start server ?

Comment: I have an error listener on socket.io, its not fired

Comment: no, its throw on production, I use pm2

Comment: @DeepKakkar, what if it's running on nodemon?

Answer (score 1):

It is because your node server has not been shut down properly but you have started another node process.
If you use Linux follow these steps as below:

1. ps -aux | grep node (get node process_number)
2. sudo kill process_number
3. start your node process

Comment: `ps -aux | grep node`

the command show me only one node process.

Comment: filling RAM can be the cause of this error? Its always more than 90%

Comment: kill the process and start your process again.what is the result?

Comment: after killing the process pm2 automatically restarted it