# NodeJS API response fails after fs.writefile

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, promise, fs

I've created an API which I want to create a file, and after the file was written, request a log API and after its response, response relatively to the user.

I've simplified the code like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const util = require('util');
const fs = require("fs-extra")

router.get('/works/', (req, res) => {
    logData(res)
})

router.get('/fails/', (req, res) => {
    let t = Date.now();
    const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile)
    writeFile(`./data/${t}.json`, 'test').then(function(){
        logData(res)
    })
})

function logData(res) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        fetch('https://webhook.site/44dad1a5-47f6-467b-9088-346e7222d7be')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(x => res.send('x'));
    });
}

module.exports = router
```

The /works/ API works fine,

but the /fails/ API fails with **Error: read ECONNRESET**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I debug error ECONNRESET in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/how-do-i-debug-error-econnreset-in-node-js)

Comment: @nbokmans no, this couldn't help, I think there may be a problem on promise chaining

Comment: @SalmanShariati ECONNRESET means the request was aborted because it could not be completed. This usually happens server side because the request is malformed or invalid. Example, file you are trying to upload exceeds file limit.

Comment: How you run your code? If you are using `nodemon` it will restart the server after you change the `.json` file in this project. Make sure that your server does not restart.

Comment: `writeFile` from `fs-extra` already supports promises. You don't need to `promisify` it. Is there any console output on the server side? If yes, please add it.

Comment: @RuslanHadyniak the problem solved when I run the code without nodemon, so would you write this as a reply with some description, I'll mark it as the answer to help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP clarified in the comments that he uses `nodemon` to run this code.

The problem is that `nodemon` watches `.json` files too and restarts the server.  So the request that changes a JSON file fails with `Error: read ECONNRESET`.

To prevent `nodemon` from restarting server when you change `.json` files see [this](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#ignoring-files).
For example, you can add `nodemon.json` [configuration file](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#config-files) to ignore `./data` directory (make sure to restart `nodemon` after this file is added):

```
{
    "ignore": ["./data"]
}
```