# Error: read ECONNRESET while connection rabbitmq with nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, rabbitmq, dockerfile

I've encountered following error message while connection our external RabbitMQ with NodeJS as follow:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

and my nodejs code is as follow:

```
const amqp_url = "amqp://un:pw@sb-mq.com:9901/my-vhost";
amqp.connect(amqp_url, function (error0, connection) {
  if (error0) {
    throw error0;
  }
  connection.createChannel(function (error1, channel) {
    if (error1) {
      throw error1;
    }
    var queue = 'hello';
    var msg = 'Hello World!';
    channel.assertQueue(queue, {
      durable: false
    });
    channel.sendToQueue(queue, Buffer.from(msg));
    console.log(" [x] Sent %s", msg);
  });
  setTimeout(function () {
    connection.close();
    process.exit(0);
  }, 500);
});
```

But the thing is when I've setup RabbidMQ locally with same configuration but using default port (like `amqp://un:pw@localhost:5672/my-vhost`), it was working perfectly. Please let me know how to troubleshoot that one, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that issue has been resolved when I've tried to use `amqps` instead of `amqp`.

Answer (score 2):

> "ECONNRESET" means the other side of the TCP conversation abruptly closed its end of the connection.

see [How do I debug error ECONNRESET in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/how-do-i-debug-error-econnreset-in-node-js)

about RabbitMQ check if rabbitmq actually is active in that port, just:

```
telnet sb-mq.com 9901
```

from your client machine and check the firewall configuration.
You may have another service running on 9901

`ECONNRESET` is network problem, rabbitmq can work in different ports without problems

Comment: I've checked both `5672` and `9901` with telnet and both can be connected.