# Node JS: Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:211:20)

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I'm trying to insert a big array of data in MySQL database with node.js.
My code works correctly with small array about 300 elements, but when I insert an array with 1M elements I have the following error:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:211:20)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:379:20)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:313:12) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  fatal: true
}
```

My query:

```
let query = "INSERT INTO transactions (customer_id, tr_date, tr_time, mcc_code, tr_type, amount, term_id) VALUES ?";
              connection.query(query, [csvData], (error, response) => {
                console.log(error || response);
              })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/how-do-i-debug-error-econnreset-in-node-js) more about the error itself. It's simply a connection error.

Why the connection fails is most likely because that insert is huge and is probably taking a long time to terminate. Also because the data being sent over the network is decent sized, the time the whole operation takes to complete is increased.

The solution to your problem is, IMO, to split the data into multiple smaller inserts (try 500, 1k, 5k, depending on the size of each row).