# nodeJS express res.download fails when bulk call

Tags: node.js, express, download

I have an API for downloading files using res.download. It works fine when single call is made.

However, when bulk call (e.g. call 10 times within 1 second), several of the request are failed and prompt below error:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
```

Can anyone explain this behavior? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

"ECONNRESET" means the other side of the TCP conversation abruptly closed its end of the connection. This is most probably due to one or more application protocol errors. You could look at the API server logs to see if it complains about something.

[How do I debug error ECONNRESET in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/how-do-i-debug-error-econnreset-in-node-js)

Your best bet is to make sure you are not throttling the API.