# Getting read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead error, while making connection with AZURE server

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

Hi all I am learning Nodejs. I am uploading file to AZURE server, but getting the below error after every 3-4 minutes. Anyone have the solution for this?

The error is ->

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at Connection._handleProtocolError 
(/Data/core/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:425:8)
at Protocol.emit (events.js:198:13)
at Protocol.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
at Protocol._delegateError 
(/Data/core/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:390:10)
at Protocol.handleNetworkError 
(/Data/core/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:363:10)
at Connection._handleNetworkError 
(/Data/core/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:420:18)
at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
```

Comment: Not the same case but I've faced ```ECONNRESET``` twice and both time it was ```node version``` related issue. You can check the version of both machines

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, changing the node version cause other issues because of  using other modules.

Comment: Hello @RakeshSaini, please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/how-do-i-debug-error-econnreset-in-node-js) and let me know if the issue is resolved or need any information.

Comment: Thank @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT For your answer, Actually the issue was in the connection waiting limit in the mysql, now its solved.

Comment: Hello @RakeshSaini, MySQL has its wait_timeout variable default value set to 28800 seconds (8 hours) - Is this the resolution you did to solve the issue?

Comment: This is solved!!

Comment: Actually the  "wait_timeout" was very low. So I increased and the issue solved. This is the final answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***"`ECONNRESET`"* means the other side of the TCP conversation abruptly closed its end of the connection. This is most probably due to one or more application protocol errors. You could look at the API server logs to see if it complains about something.**

Glad @[RakeshSaini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15915172/rakesh-saini) that you identified the error which was in the connection waiting limit in the MySQL and for fixing the issue.