# node web app stops working after sometime

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

web page loads successfully but after sometime it stops by this error
events.js:377
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: read ECONNRESET

```
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)
```

Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:

```
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:475:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {errno: -4077,  code: 'ECONNRESET',   syscall: 'read'}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I debug error ECONNRESET in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/how-do-i-debug-error-econnreset-in-node-js)