# sending message using whatsapp cloud api with node.js and express

Tags: node.js, http, whatsapp

I'm currently working on a project that need to send whatsapp's messages,
for this work i'm using my favorite node.js framework Express.js.

Honestly i have never done such kind of work it's my first time dealing with whatsapp cloud api , i did read the entire documentation about how to have everything done with express but when i try to apply what i learned it turns into a nightmare your help will be very important.

Here is the example configuration of my code

```js
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/Phone Number ID/messages',
        data: {
            message_product: 'whatsapp',
            to: 'client number',
            type: "template",
            template: {
                name: "hello_world",
                language: {
                    code: "en_US"
                }
            },
        },
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer  + token",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }).then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message)
    })
```

And here is the error that i'm getting

```
read ECONNRESET
```

Comment: can you check your api url. it seems wrong.

Comment: that is the url provided by META on there dashboard and it works for other people

Comment: it response: 
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'Phone Number ID' does not exist, ....

so it means "you have to pass real object id"

Comment: it seems that the request doesn't even hit the API 

this is the error message that i'm getting ' read ECONNRESET '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working in same idea of project
and it worked for me

```
var options = {
method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/PHONE_NUMBER_ID/messages',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer TOKEN',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data: {
    messaging_product: 'whatsapp',
    to: '{number}',
    type: 'template',
    template: {name: 'hello_world', language: {code: 'en_US'}}
  }
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a function I created to send requests to the /messages endpoint using NodeJs and Express:

```
export async function sendWhatsAppResponse(parameters = {}, responseText = ""){
  //create payload to be posted
  const whatsappMessageURL = `https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/${parameters.phoneNumberId}/messages`;
  const responsePayload = {
    messaging_product: 'whatsapp',
    recipientType: 'individual',
    type: 'text',
    to: parameters.userPhoneNumber,
    text: {
      preview_url: false,
      body: responseText
    }
  }
  const header = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${envVariables.WAToken}`
  }

  //send response
  try {
    axios.post(whatsappMessageURL,  responsePayload, {
      headers: header
    })  
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

You need to ensure that your access token has the correct permissions and that the phone number ID you are inserting into your URL contains the correct value found on your whatsapp business platform > whatsapp > Getting started.  The ECONNRSET error is a connection issue with the API you are trying to reach, see [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17637900/15082999).