# Why is this error occurring in React "ECONNRESET "?

Tags: reactjs, npm, econnreset

I was creating a react app through box create-react-app my app , when I got this npm ECONNRESET error.I am quite new to reactjs so I don't know much about this.so please help me.
I didn't know what to do so I came here.I am using vs code btw.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I debug error ECONNRESET in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/how-do-i-debug-error-econnreset-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

The ECONNRESET error is typically related to network connectivity issues

Here are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot

```
npm cache clean --force
npx create-react-app my-app
npm install -g yarn
yarn create react-app my-app
node --version
npm --version
```

Comment: Is it a proxy issue??