# Enabling Server Sent Events (SSE) in Linux Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, server-sent-events

I am trying to get Server Sent Events to work on my Linux Azure App Service but I cannot figure out how, I followed a lot of tutorials but they are all doing stuff on the programming side while I thing some server configuration needs to change. The following call is what I am using in my API. I added:

- `HttpContext IHttpResponseBodyFeature DisableBuffering()`
- Used the `IHttpResponseBodyFeature.Writer`
- Returning correct headers

The thing is that everything is and has been working without these modification with a local ASP.NET Core Environment and a VUE frontend. When looking at postman I can also see that the server is sending a `ECONNRESET` response after the first write.

I am using using a B1 Tier for my app service, so SSE should be allowed, I tried configuring web.config (I think Linux App Service is not using iis?) like this (added `responseBufferLimit`). Is there anything I am missing? I really don't need the overhead of SignalR so I need to do it like this.

[image: Postman Result]

```cs
[HttpGet("ask/{question}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string question)
{
    var g = Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IHttpResponseBodyFeature>();
    g.DisableBuffering();
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
    Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    Response.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");

    var receivedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"event: received\ndata: started processing\n\n");
    await g.Writer.WriteAsync(receivedBytes);
    await g.Writer.FlushAsync();
    //await Response.Body.WriteAsync(receivedBytes, 0, receivedBytes.Length);
    //await Response.Body.FlushAsync();

    var graphClient = new SimpleGraphClient(_graphUserService.GetToken());

    await foreach (var evDataTuple in _questionService.AskQuestion(question, graphClient, PlatformType.Web))
    {
        var eventData = $"event: {evDataTuple.ev}\ndata: {evDataTuple.data}\n\n";
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(eventData);

        //await Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        //await Response.Body.FlushAsync();
        await g.Writer.WriteAsync(bytes);
        await g.Writer.FlushAsync();
    }

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

web.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: could you tell your framework and where you are getting an error

Comment: @Sampath The framework is ASPNETCORE and the error is nowhere, the server returns the ECONNRESET without logging anything to console

Comment: The "Error: read ECONNRESET" occurs when the server unexpectedly closes the connection which causes the HTTP request to fail. This is often caused due to networking issues caused by a Virtual Private Network (VPN). If the endpoint is public, try to switch off your VPN and reissue the request if you use a [VPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/how-do-i-debug-error-econnreset-in-node-js#:~:text=%22ECONNRESET%22%20means%20the%20other%20side%20of%20the%20TCP,logs%20to%20see%20if%20it%20complains%20about%20something.).

Comment: @Sampath The Server does receive the first packets since the "received: started processing" message is received by the controllers first call. This indicates that it is not a network issue right?

Comment: I am trying to implement something similar to what you did. I have basically the same setup as you, the only difference is the tier that I am using Premium V2 P1V2. However, I am not even receiving the connected response. It is like the response is not getting flushed by the buffer. I have no idea what is happening and how to solve it.

Comment: @GabrielHeming My problem ended up being my Error middleware trying to override the Header content type to text and thus faililng on that, so not getting any response or error logging.

Comment: I guess I found out the issue. It seems that azure flushes the headers (allowing to connect) only after the first byte from the body is sent to the output buffer. As the connection was being established without any data output, the headers aren't being flushed as well.

Comment: I think you can fix that by calling DisableBuffering() on the `IHttpResponseBodyFeature` like this: `var g = Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IHttpResponseBodyFeature>(); g.DisableBuffering();`

Comment: That is not enough (though it is not necessary). I made several tests on Azure App Service, and confirmed that the headers are not going to be flushed until something is written on the body. After I added `await Response.Body.WriteAsync("data: handshake\n\n");` and `await Response.Body.FlushAsync();` just to flush some bytes to the body, it started to work properly. On my tests, disabling the buffering or adding web.config had no effect at all, and were unnecessary. In any case, your example showed me that SSE works on App Service and it was something that I was missing.